# SQL query with decoding and comparison in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following requirement for writing a query in oracle.

I need to fetch all the records from a Table T1 (it has two date columns D1 and D2)based on two dynamic values V1 and V2. These V1 and V2 are passed dynamically from application.
The possible values for V1 are 'Less than' or 'Greater than'. The possible value for V2 is a integer number.

Query i need to write:

If V1 is passed as 'Less than' and V2 is passed as 5, then I need to return all the rows in T1 WHERE D1-D2 < 5.

If V1 passed as 'Greater than' and V2 passed as 8, then I need to return all the rows in T1 WHERE D1-D2 > 8;

I could think that this can be done using a CASE statement in where clause. But not sure how to start.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Store V2 in a variable and reference that in the where clause. In order to determine the query based on the operator based in you could build the where clause dynamically http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure, or use an If Else clause and do the same selects essentially but with different comparison operators

Comment: How is it possible? Do you mean that you have one variable, that could have the value either 'Less than' or 'Greater than'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write this as:

```
select *
from t1
where (v1 = 'Less Than' and D1 - D2 < v2) or
      (v1 = 'Greater Than' and D1 - D2 > v2)
```

A `case` statement isn't needed.

Comment: I had the same solution)) you are the first, I won't post mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *
from T1
where case when V1 = 'LESS THAN' THEN D1 - D2 < V2 ELSE D1 - D2 > V2
```

This assume if V1 is not LESS THAN the only other value is greater than.  If necessary you can use more than one case statement but this should get you started.

Comment: This is not a valid query in Oracle. You can't have comparison operators (such as `=`, `<`, or `>`) within a `case` statement. Also, the `case` statement is not terminated.

Answer (score 0):

`PL/SQL` Solution, *not* straight forward, but can be *customized* for complex logics!

**Create nested table sql objects**

```
    CREATE TYPE MY_RECORD_TYPE IS OBJECT
    ( 
      D1 VARCHAR2(100),
      D2 VARCHAR2(100),
      D3 VARCHAR2(100),
      D4 VARCHAR2(100)
    );
    /

    CREATE TYPE MY_TABLE_TYPE IS TABLE OF MY_RECORD_TYPE;
    /
```

**Here is the Function that returns a nested table.**

```
   create or replace function check_me(v1 varchar2,v2 number)
    return MY_TABLE_TYPE
    is
    v_query varchar2(4000);
    my_cur sys_refcursor;

    v_record MYTABLE%ROWTYPE; -- Create a local record of table's row type

    v_nested MY_TABLE_TYPE := MY_TABLE_TYPE();

    I NUMBER;
    begin
     v_query := 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE D1 - D2 ';
     IF( UPPER(v1) = UPPER('Less Than')) THEN
       v_query := v_query||' > :V2';
     ELSE
       v_query := v_query||' < :V2';
     END IF;

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_query);
     OPEN my_cur FOR v_query USING V2;

     I:=0;
     LOOP
       FETCH my_cur INTO v_record;
       EXIT WHEN my_cur%NOTFOUND;

       v_nested.EXTEND(1);
       I := I + 1;

       /* Copy it into the nested table - Painful!!*/ 
       v_nested(I) := MY_RECORD_TYPE(
                                      v_record.D1,
                                      v_record.d2,
                                      v_record.D3,
                                      v_record.D4
                                     ); 
      END LOOP;

    CLOSE my_cur;--CLose the cursor
    return v_nested;--return the nested table
    end;
    /
```

**And you can run as,**

```
select * FROM TABLE(check_me(',',5));
```

Comment: This is vast overkill for the question at hand. Why would you do this instead of using `or`?

Comment: Overcomplicated may be @Allan but not a bad performing one isnt it? Just in case of more complex logics. What if the minus operation itself is generic, say an addition or something else.. The OR conditions keep growing. but this pl sql , work the same way. May help someone, thats why I mentioned it in answer as first point.

Comment: Actually, performance will be worse than it should be. Because you're concatenating in the variables, the optimizer will need a seperate plan for every variable. You're defeating the cache without a good reason. 

You're also eliminating the advantage of using a SQL-native language: instead of validating the SQL syntax at compile-time, you're doing it at run-time. As your function gets more complex, the chances of an edge-case where the SQL is broken increases.

Comment: Ah, @Allan, Making this as bind variables is _soo_ Simple. Updated the answer. I was intended to just provide a hint for `PL/SQL` usage.